# How to get monthly data using scala & play with month parameter?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am new with scala and play and going to make an API using them. I have made a method that will take a month as parameter and will return all the data with that month. where `date` is `Instant`.

```
val queryByMonth = Compiled((month: Rep[Int]) => table.filter(_.date.getMonth === month))
def getMonthlyData(month: Int) = db.run(queryByMonth(month).result)
```

N.B: `_.date.getMonth === month` is a psudo checking.
I don't know how to get month from `Instant` by query. So what should I do?

Comment: You need to have a much more precise question? What have you tried? What DB/store have you chosen? Which lib do you use to access it?

Comment: look `date` contains value as like `2016-06-28 00:00:00+06` that means this is for JUNE [06 as month]. I would like to fetch all the data for JUNE by calling getMonthlyData(6) or getMonthlyData(06) --- @ cchantep

Comment: I am working with SLICK for this project --- @cchantep

Comment: It is possible, but you need to attach slick extensions. Firstly tell me which database do you use?

Comment: Currently I am using POSTGRES database for this application. --- @MariuszBeltowski